# Get Max with other columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to get `Max(OD.CYCLE_END_DATE)` with other columns from below query?

```
    SELECT   C.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
            ,C.USR_SPE_Membership_Status
            ,OD.PRODUCT_CODE
            ,OD.CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE
            ,OD.CYCLE_END_DATE
            ,LINE_STATUS_CODE
FROM CUSTOMER C
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_DETAIL OD
      ON C.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
      AND C.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_SUB_CUSTOMER_ID
      AND OD.PRODUCT_CODE in ('PROFESSIONAL','LIFE','STUDENT','STAFF')
     --AND OD.CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE <= GETDATE()
     AND OD.CYCLE_END_DATE >= GETDATE()

where C.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID= '3420065'
```

### Results

```
MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID  USR_SPE_Membership_Status   PRODUCT_CODE    CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE    CYCLE_END_DATE  LINE_STATUS_CODE
3420065             Paid Member                 LIFE            2013-01-01          2013-12-31          A
3420065             Paid Member                 LIFE            2014-01-01          2014-12-31          A
```

I need `2014-12-31` row.

Comment: Search for row_number with over clause - it will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

You've got options,

you can take the `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` fields that you don't want to take the `MAX()` of,

or you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
WITH    cte
      AS ( SELECT   C.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID ,
                    C.USR_SPE_Membership_Status ,
                    OD.PRODUCT_CODE ,
                    OD.CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE ,
                    OD.CYCLE_END_DATE ,
                    LINE_STATUS_CODE ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY C.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY OD.CYCLE_END_DATE DESC ) RN
           FROM     CUSTOMER C
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_DETAIL OD ON C.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
                                                       AND C.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_SUB_CUSTOMER_ID
                                                       AND OD.PRODUCT_CODE IN (
                                                       'PROFESSIONAL',
                                                       'LIFE', 'STUDENT',
                                                       'STAFF' )
                     --AND OD.CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE <= GETDATE()
                                                       AND OD.CYCLE_END_DATE >= GETDATE()
           WHERE    C.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = '3420065'
         )
SELECT  *
FROM    cte
WHERE   RN = 1
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a number to each row.

`PARTITION BY` is optional, but used to start the numbering over for each value in that group,

ie: if you `PARTITION BY MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID`  then for each unique Customer ID value the numbering would start over at 1.

`ORDER BY` of course is used to define how the counting should go,

and is required in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Answer (score 0):

In order to return the data from other columns when one is using `MAX()` you must include them either in other aggregate functions or in a `GROUP BY` clause which would be added after your `WHERE` caluse

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT   C.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
            ,C.USR_SPE_Membership_Status
            ,OD.PRODUCT_CODE
            ,OD.CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE
            ,OD.CYCLE_END_DATE
            ,LINE_STATUS_CODE,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE DESC) AS [number]
FROM CUSTOMER C
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_DETAIL OD
      ON C.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
      AND C.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_SUB_CUSTOMER_ID
      AND OD.PRODUCT_CODE in ('PROFESSIONAL','LIFE','STUDENT','STAFF')
     --AND OD.CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE <= GETDATE()
     AND OD.CYCLE_END_DATE >= GETDATE()

where C.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID= '3420065'
) A 
WHERE A.[number] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a subquery that returns one value in your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT   C.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
        ,C.USR_SPE_Membership_Status
        ,OD.PRODUCT_CODE
        ,OD.CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE
        ,OD.CYCLE_END_DATE
        ,LINE_STATUS_CODE
        ,(SELECT MAX(CYCLE_END_DATE) 
             FROM ORDER_DETAIL 
             WHERE PRODUCT_CODE in ('PROFESSIONAL','LIFE','STUDENT','STAFF')
                 AND CYCLE_END_DATE >= GETDATE()
                 AND C.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
                 AND C.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID = SHIP_SUB_CUSTOMER_ID
            ) MAX_CYCLE_END_DATE
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Cross Apply:

```
SELECT   C.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
            ,C.USR_SPE_Membership_Status
            ,CrossApplyTable.PRODUCT_CODE
            ,CrossApplyTable.CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE
            ,CrossApplyTable.CYCLE_END_DATE
            ,LINE_STATUS_CODE
FROM CUSTOMER C
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 * 
            FROM ORDER_DETAIL OD
            WHERE C.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
            AND C.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_SUB_CUSTOMER_ID
            AND OD.PRODUCT_CODE in ('PROFESSIONAL','LIFE','STUDENT','STAFF')
     --     AND OD.CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE <= GETDATE()
            AND OD.CYCLE_END_DATE >= GETDATE() 
            ORDER BY CYCLE_END_DATE DESC) CrossApplyTable

where C.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = '3420065'
```